# Why casting integer is giving reverse answer?

Tags: c++, casting, byte

I am casting an unsigned int(64 bit) for some use case inside the program(C++). I tried with an example and wondering why the answer is in reverse of what it actually should be?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::string string_to_hex(const std::string& input)
{
    static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    std::string output;
    output.reserve(input.length() * 2);
    for (unsigned char c : input)
    {
        output.push_back(hex_digits[c >> 4]);
        output.push_back(hex_digits[c & 15]);
    }
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t foo = 258; // (00000001)(00000010) => (01)(02)

    std::string out = "";
    out.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&foo), sizeof(foo));
    
    std::cout << "out: " << string_to_hex(out) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I intentionally used that number(258) to see the result something like: (00)(00)(00)(00)(00)(00)(01)(02) after converting to hex. But it is giving me the result:

```
out: 0201000000000000
```

I asked one related question earlier: [Why same values inside string even after swapping the underlying integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572605/why-same-values-inside-string-even-after-swapping-the-underlying-integer), but I'm not sure they have the same underlying cause.

It maybe a trivial mistake from my side, but I thought it is worth posting and sort it out incase I'm missing some concept.

Comment: It looks like you are using a **little-endian** machine.

Comment: If you want a string, why not use e.g. `std::ostringstream` and the normal streaming manipulators to get it? As in `std::string output = (std::ostringstream() << std::hex << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << foo).str();`

Comment: And if you have C++20 and [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) then `std::format("{:016x}", foo)`

Comment: I recommend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness -- bytes of integral types are not always stored in memory they way you think. Most modern hardware uses the "little endian" format, and many network protocols use "big endian" instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the response, so actually using the cast for byte wise handling of data for some program purpose